# Visual Studio 2010 Code Coverage - Cannot find the back up file, created by instrumentation utility

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am trying to run code coverage in VS 2010 and I am running into the following error.  No coverage information is generated.

Code coverage in-place instrumentation: Cannot fully backup the binary 'MyProject.dll'. Cannot find the back up file, created by instrumentation utility: 'MyProject.dll.orig'.

Answer (score 4):

Check which artifacts are selected for code coverage for your test run config - it's quite well hidden:

- Under menu: **Test -> Edit Test Settings** select your active test setting
- In the **Test settings** Dialog select the **Data and Diagnostics** tab
- Select the Code Coverage item, and then hit the **Configure** button above

[image]

- This opens up the **Code Coverage Detail** window. Check the **MyProject.dll** that is giving you problems: Does the dll exist? Is it a debug build? Is it signed? Do you have any tests which hits this project?

Answer (score 0):

According to SP's answer to a similar question at [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/tfsbuild/thread/31a801b5-756b-4ec5-91a7-5cefc4ee5022), this error can occur if the project or a file in the project does your project does not contain instrumentable code - eg, interfaces only, or resources only.  Is that the case in your project?