# Code coverage in-place instrumentation: Cannot fully backup the binary error

Tags: tfsbuild, mstest, msbuild-4.0

Can anybody help with this error in the log of my Team Build 2010 build? It only seems to occur when I have two build agents running on the same machine at the same time.

> Run has the following issue(s):
>
> Code coverage in-place instrumentation:
>
> Cannot fully backup the binary
> 'C:\Builds\3\MyProject\Binaries\MyProject.UserManager.DataModel.dll'.
>
> Cannot find the back up file, created by instrumentation utility:
> 'C:\Builds\3\MyProject\Binaries\MyProject.UserManager.DataModel.dll.orig'.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I also got it.

Comment: @Tommy No, but I've not seen it recently so may have fixed it without realising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For coverage, if you use in place, mstest will create backup location with the uninstumented dll's in them. these will be removed after execution. so:

1. It might be that your first build is removing them of the second. Given your build path looks like: C:\Builds\3\MyProject, it means the agents (number 3 is the agent number) use seperated directories (default, but not always the case).
2. You had issues with pdb settings and or coverage settings, so no instrumented dll's where created: [Visual Studio 2010 Code Coverage - Cannot find the back up file, created by instrumentation utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909260/visual-studio-2010-code-coverage-cannot-find-the-back-up-file-created-by-inst)

Given you aren't seeing it anymore, 2 is most likely.